# “error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax” en MonoDevelop C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, linux-mint, mono

Obtengo este mensaje cuando intento crear una solucion en MonoDevelop:

```
Getting restore information for project /home/user/Projects/myApp/myApp/myApp.csproj
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.203/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(54,5) : error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')". Method '[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier' not found. The invocation of the static method must be in the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), for example, $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)). Check that all parameters are defined, of the correct type, and specified in the proper order.
Unable to create package spec for project. '/home/user/Projects/myApp/myApp/myApp.csproj'
```

Cuando intento compilar me da esto:

```
Error: NuGet packages need to be restored before compiling. The NuGet MSBuild targets, which are required for build, are missing. NuGet MSBuild targets are generated when restoring NuGet packages. (myApp)
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar este problema?

Comment: estoy confundido, sino estoy equivocado, Mono es de Xamarin. En que linea te da ese error, y coloca el codigo.

Comment: intenta actualizar mono: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/20250

Comment: @RamiroBarone Al momento de crear una solución